# How to connect weird fridge water line

Tags: water, refrigerator, adapter

I have this water line for my fridge. I don't know how it's suppose to connect to the water since it's just a plastic piece. The gold piece is where it's suppose to connect but doesn't connect to the plasitc at all. I looked in the plumbing section at Lowes, but couldn't find any adapter for it.

[image: water line and what it's suppose to connect to]
[image: water line and what it's suppose to connect to]

When I unscrew the gold piece the line fits but the silver screw isn't long enough to screw into it.
[image]
[image]

**Edit:** I cut the line and it connects but it's leaking.
[image]
[image]

whirlpool refrigerator model: ed5nhgxmq10

Comment: Are you sure the silver piece goes with the brass fitting? The brass fitting looks like a complete compression fitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some sort of plastic water line that works with a very specific type of stop valve that looks like the the one in the back of the last picture.  The plastic seats on the 1/4" valve body and the compression nut keeps it tight.

For some reason, it looks like you don't have the other side of that valve, and you are trying to connect it to a 1/2 x 3/8 valve with a 3/8 x 1/4 reducer.

If I had to do this myself, I'd either replace the stop valve with a 1/2 x 1/4, and see if you could get it to work with no brass ferrule,  or I'd cut the water line straight behind the compression nut, use a double end press-fit connector such as this one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/John-Guest-1-4-in-O-D-x-1-4-in-O-D-NPTF-Polypropylene-Push-to-Connect-Coupling-Fitting-803149/300753474
combined with a short piece of copper 1/4 tubing to your existing compression fitting.

Alternatively, they make metal inserts that stabilize the plastic water line, and you can just use the compression fitting that you have on that valve like you were trying to.

Edit:
Technique for using plastic compression fittings with brass reinforcement inserts is here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=127&v=aFpZfr0YQ28&feature=emb_logo

Comment: I don't understand. 1. I don't think I can find 1/2x1/4 stop valve that will connect to this directly because the silver nut on the line doesn't go far enough. I see the thing in the back of the pic but it can't screw into it. 2. I can cut the line and get that coupling but idk what 1/4 tubing I would need and how it would connect. 3. Idk what the metal inserts are and if it would seal the water.

Comment: you hack the end of the waterline off, and it becomes a a regualr 1/4" water line.

Comment: Yes, cut your plastic water line behind the integrated flange, then slide the brass compression nut and ferrule that came with your brass adapter fitting onto the plastic line. Insert the plastic line into the brass adapter fitting (make sure it is inserted all the way in). Then, while holding the line all the way in, slide the ferrule and nut toward the fitting threads and tighten the nut firmly.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I cut the line and it fits but it's leaking. Do you think this brass insert and sleeve will stop the leaking? https://tinyurl.com/ybxhofqj

Comment: @PhilipRego  I'd use a poly ferrule and a brass insert, but you also have to make sure that the cut is straight and flat.  The brass ferrule might work as well, but you really need to reinforce the end so that it makes a tight seal with the fitting.

Comment: If the plastic tube is **hard** (like poly) tubing it should work without the insert, and a brass or plastic ferrule should work; however the insert certainly won't hurt anything. If the tube is **soft** (like vinyl) the insert is mandatory and a plastic ferrule should be used. The most common reason for compression fitting leaks is that the nut was not tightened enough (at least that has been my experience).

Comment: P.S.- I don't know if it is a camera effect or what, but the tube looks off-center coming out of the nut in your last pic. Are you certain that the nut and ferrule are both for 1/4" tube? The hole in the nut should be 1/4" in diameter or maybe very slightly larger...

Comment: If everything is sized properly it should work.  You must **tighten the compression nut much tighter then you think**. As it tightens down on the ferrule it compresses the ferrule, conforming it into the seat. If you do not tighten it enough it will  not conform and it will leak. You need two wrench's to do this, one the hold the fitting very firm and the other to tighten the nut.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I attatched the brass insert and plastic piece and it's not leaking anymore. Working well. Thank you